# How does Immutability leads to Scalability?

Tags: functional-programming

Can anyone give a deep insight into how immutability can lead to scalabilty? Or is it a misconception?

Comment: This is too broad for SO, which specialises in narrow, specific questions, unfortunately. But even so, this is insanely broad, and kind of tackles this from the wrong angle. Immutability is part of paring down integration points and state which make understanding the dynamic behaviour of a system difficult.

Comment: I would say that the concepts are orthogonal, you can have immutability without being scalable, and you can be scalable without immutability.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't, at least not really.

Immutability lets you make assumptions about what you can do with the data/memory/etc. and that can give you solutions that are more scalable. For example, if you have a bunch of immutable sets of data as inputs for a function you have a deterministic results which allows for caching and easy parallelisation. The entire story is a bit more complicated but that's the basic idea.

You should note that caching and parallelisation are not exclusive for immutable data, it just makes it easier to implement.